# Meteor not setting the DOCTYPE correctly

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have been trying to make a small app work on IE9+, however meteor is setting the DOCTYPE to

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html -->
```

This happens only on IE, any idea on how to fix this, or what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking around for a long time I found the answer!

This should go in the server side of the meteor app.

```
connectHandler.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains');
      res.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=Edge,chrome=1');
      return next();
  })
```